# Javascript formula for subtracting sequential values as prior ones reach zero

Tags: javascript, subtraction, sequential

I'm working within a proprietary software in my company, and I've discovered that I can implement JavaScript code to create certain actions within it. I'll get right to the point...

What I have:

Three fields - `FieldA, FieldB, and FieldC.`

What I am already doing:

```
(FieldA + FieldB + FieldC) = SUM
```

How I need to affect the above formula:

```
Subtract 75 from FieldC, 
 IF FieldC < 75, 
then when FieldC reaches 0, 
subtract the remainder from FieldB,
 IF FieldB < remainder, 
then when FieldB reaches 0, 
subtract remainder from FieldA.
```

Example user input:

```
FieldA = 20
FieldB = 30
FieldC = 40
```

Subtracting 75 would leave me with

```
FieldA = 15
FieldB = 0
FieldC = 0
```

And unfortunately, I cannot simply subtract 75 from the SUM, as there is a deeper meaning to why I am manipulating these individual field values.

Anybody have an idea how I could implement this? Even just pointing me to a function, and I can read up on it myself.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Just so it is entirely clear, are you giving us pseudocode, or are these commands related to your proprietary software?

Comment: Do you need to substract 75 from FieldC as many times as it reaches 0?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't really do just subtraction, because how you pointed out this algorithm has the same result as (a - x + b + c). 
If you could wrap this variables in an array, then using map function could be an elegant solution.

Using variables is a bit more tricky. In JS you can have functions with variable number of arguments, but you cannot like in for example python return multiple values, but you can use  **destructuring assignment** instead of trying to make it work with global variables. Of course destructuring assignment is not supported in IE.

```js
function substractArray(amount, items){
 return items.map(function(item){
  item = item - amount;
  amount = (-1)*item;
  if(item < 0){
   item = 0;
        }
  if(amount < 0){
   amount = 0;
        }
  return item;
    })
}

function substractVariables(amount,...args){
 var items = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
 return substractArray(amount, items)

}

var data = [40,30,20];
console.log("substractArray");
console.log(substractArray(75,data));

var fieldA = 20;
var fieldB = 30;
var fieldC = 40;

var result = substractVariables(75,fieldC, fieldB, fieldA);

console.log("substractVariables");
console.log(result);

console.log("destructuring assignment");
[fieldC, fieldB, fieldA] = result;
console.log(fieldC, fieldB, fieldA);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to have some other scenarios to test this against if you have any.

```js
const fieldA = 20
const fieldB = 30
const fieldC = 40
let subtractor = 75

let fields = [fieldC, fieldB, fieldA]
let fieldTracker = 0

while (subtractor > 0) {
  if (fields[fieldTracker] === 0 && fieldTracker !== fields.length-1) fieldTracker+=1

  subtractor-=1
  fields[fieldTracker]-=1
}

console.log('remaining amount', Math.abs(fields.reduce((prev, current) => prev+current , 0)))
console.log('fields Array', fields)
```

Below is the logic put into a `Function`.
First argument is the `subtractor` and then the rest or the arguments are the integers to subtract against.

```js
const getRemainder = (subtractor = 0, ...fields) => {
  let fieldTracker = 0

  while (subtractor > 0) {
    if (fields[fieldTracker] === 0 && fieldTracker !== fields.length-1) fieldTracker+=1

    subtractor-=1
    fields[fieldTracker]-=1
  }
  
  return Math.abs(fields.reduce((prev, current) => prev+current , 0))
}

const remainder = getRemainder(75, 40, 30, 20)
console.log(remainder)
```

Comment: I think I got it sorted in my own way, but thanks to your code.
I am going to answer my question so you can see what I did.
It's working on my end, but that doesn't mean it is an elegant solution.
Any feedback you may have would be welcome!
Thanks Francis

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total novice, so this may not make sense. Below is what I arrived at, and it looks to be working great. My team and I have not been able to find any issues in testing it.

I greatly appreciate the help offered by everyone. The kicker for me was learning that I can use absolute value in JS, which I didn't know until I saw Francis' code.

Thanks everyone!

```js
    var Quad
    var Dual
    var FinalValue

    if (FieldC < 75)
    {
    Quad = 75 - FieldC
    Dual = Quad - FieldB
    if (Dual > 0)
    {FinalValue = Dual - FieldA
    if (FinalValue >= 0)
    {0}
    else
    {Math.abs(FinalValue)}
    }
    else
    {FinalValue = 2 * Math.abs(Dual) + FieldA
    FinalValue}


    }

    else
    {(FieldC - 75) * 4 + FieldB * 2 + FieldA}
```